# Saving data from visited web pages, no spider, accessible from outside

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I would like to perform a test on the content of all the pages I visit using Chrome. If the page HTML contains a string that follows a certain rule, I would like to save the string somewhere.

Rules:

1. The pages to be checked are the ones I encounter during my normal browsing; I don't want to use a script to open multiple pages
2. Data should persist for many days (this excludes localStorage)
3. Saved data must be in a single pool, even if coming from multiple pages and servers
4. It should be easy to export the data

My best solution, up to now, is to:

- Define a web page savedata.php in my localhost web server, that saves the GET argument it receives into a database
- Use a TamperMonkey script, that when the visited page follows the rule, extracts data, opens a tab with savedata.php passing the argument as GET

This has many limitations. When a string is saved, a new tab is opened, and has to be closed manually later.

This is a sample of my code.
Can you suggest another method, or improve the one I have chosen (for instance to avoid opening a tag?)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         CheckData
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Get data out of a web page
// @author       CB
// @match        http://localhost:8000/test1.php
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {

    // I want the page to fully load before processing    
    setTimeout( delayedStuff, 5000 )


function delayedStuff() {

    const dataFound = document.querySelector("#mystuff > div.mydiv").textContent
    
    if ( dataFollowsRule( dataFound ) ) {
        window.open( 'http://localhost:8000/savedata.php?data=' + dataFound ) ;
    }
    
}

})();
```

Comment: So what is the question exactly? What is wrong with what you did?

Comment: Biggest problem is, when a string is saved, a new tab is opened, and has to be closed manually later. I would like a solution without this inconvenience.

Comment: 1. localStorage is not working because you are talking multiple origins, not because it is not persistent. Local storage lives until you delete it. 2. Use fetch: `fetch(\` http://localhost:8000/savedata.php?data=${dataFound}\`)` but since you use http, you will need to allow the browser to fetch http

Comment: Fully loaded: `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=> { /* your stuff */});` possible with combination of a patches ajaxComplete

Comment: "since you use http, you will need to allow the browser to fetch http" you mean http vs https, right? And how do I tell the browser to allow fetching http?

Comment: So make an ajax/fetch request or a JSONP call or iframe. Biggest issue you will face is if the website is dynamically loaded, not sure how you are going to detect what you are looking for.

Comment: Should you want to save/access something across multiple origins, see: [`GM_getValue`](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#api:GM_getValue), [`GM_setValue()`](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#api:GM_setValue).

Comment: I understand that GM_getValue is deprecated